# Using relative paths in gnuplot plot files

Tags: gnuplot, relative-path

In a gnuplot instruction file, is it possible to indicate relative paths for the data source files and for the output? The paths must be relative to the gnuplot instruction file path.

**Context**
I have large data files containing between 12 to 50 x-y curves that I process using PHP scripts and gnuplot in order to provide nice graphic views of the data. The views are generated using gnuplot and for each view, I have one .csv file, one gnuplot plotting instruction file and one graphic.

Everything is nicely sorted into folders. Usually, in a folder, the graphics are at the top level, then in a source/subfolder are the .csv and gnuplot files.

Sometimes, I need to slightly change the graphic. So I edit the gnuplot file, and I plot it again by calling gnuplot directly. Everything is fine, until I move the folders elsewhere. Which I do frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify relative paths in the gnuplot file:

```
set output '../path/to/outputs/output.eps'
plot '../path/to/csv/input.csv'
```

works fine.  If you want to specify paths as arguments to the script, I recommend a bash wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

# argument 1 is path to input
# argument 2 is path to output

gnuplot << EOF
set terminal ...
set output '$2/output'

plot '$1/input1.csv', \
     '$1/input2.csv' ...
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I get : "Line 69: warning: Skipping unreadable file". I am using gnuplot 4.6, installed with macports on MAC OS 10.8.2. Is the path relative to the plot instruction file, or to the current directory in the shell ?

Comment: After testing it seems it is relative to the current selected directory in the shell.

Comment: Well, your message does not strictly answer my question. But, as the answer I seek appears to be: NO, your suggestion is the way to go. So it may help others.

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled onto using `loadpath` to get data loaded relative to one's `$HOME`:

```
set loadpath system('readlink -f ~/.gnuplot.scripts')
```

Of course, this is for un*x systems.