# gnuplot with a variable in the path to a file

Tags: linux, variables, gnuplot

I need to run gnuplot scripts on different devices.  The file structure is the same on the devices, once I get to a particular directory, but the paths to those directories are different.  I think I need to have a variable in the path name that I can change according to which device I am on.

I thought the following would work, [because I found something similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911128/using-relative-paths-in-gnuplot-plot-files), but it doesn't:

```
path_to_directory="/desktop/path/to/directory"
# path_to_directory="laptop/path/to/directory"
# the line above is commented out but it can be included 
# if I want to switch from my desktop to my laptop
path_to_file="$path_to_directory/path/to/file"
plot path_to_file ...
```

A warning message says: Skipping unreadable file "$path_to_directory/path/to/file"

Do you know how I can include a variable in the path of a gnuplot script, so that I can switch easily between paths?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gnuplot you don't use `$` to indicate variables as you do in bash. You would do a concatenation operation with a dot:

```
path_to_directory="/desktop/path/to/directory"
path_to_file=path_to_directory."/path/to/file"
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to concatenate two string variables with the `.` operator:

```
path_to_directory = "/desktop/path/to/directory"
path_to_file = path_to_directory . "/path/to/file"
plot path_to_file ...
```

You can also define a default path which can be overridden:

```
default_path_to_directory = "/desktop/path/to/directory"
if (!exists("path_to_directory")) path_to_directory = default_path_to_directory

path_to_file = path_to_directory . "/path/to/file"
plot path_to_file ...
```

Now you *can* override the `path_to_directory` but must not: e.g. when calling gnuplot like `gnuplot -e "path_to_directory='...'" script.gp` or with a configuration file.